# ImmutableList.of was working but suddenly stopped working

Tags: java, immutability

I have the following code. Not sure what happened but it was working until 1 hour ago and I didn't change anything, and it's not working now.

```
private final List<People> people;
private List<People> friend;

method() {
    friend= ImmutableList.of(people);
}
```

I get this error message when I try to compile:

```
incompatible types: inference variable E has incompatible bounds

[ERROR]     equality constraints: com.app.People
[ERROR]     lower bounds: java.util.List<com.app.People>
```

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: There is no `ImmutableList.of(..)` method taking a list

Answer (score 5):

You're invoking [`ImmutableList.of(E element)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html#of-E-) which returns an `ImmutableList` of `E`. In this case, your `E` is `List<People>` (the type of the variable `people`), so the final type of `ImmutableList.of(people)` is `List<List<People>>`.

It looks like you wanted to create a copy of `people`, and for that there's another method: [`ImmutableList.copyOf(Collection<E> elements)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html#copyOf-java.util.Collection-)

Therefore, your code should look like this:

```
friend = ImmutableList.copyOf(people);
```

Comment: P.S. If your `People` class is a class representing a single person, it should perhaps be called `Person`, that's by convention. The name `people` (plural) for a list of people is good. On the other hand, the name `friend` (singular) for a list of friends is not what we'd normally use. If you have multiple friends, or a collection of friends, call the variable `friends`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ImmutableList.copyOf` instead of `ImmutableList.of`.